# CMake doesn't find Boost libraries

Tags: windows, boost, cmake

I'm trying to use a CMake script to compile a Boost-based application on Windows.
The header-only libraries work fine, but CMake fails to find the libraries (the following Boost libraries could not be found: `boost_serialization`). The relevant part of the CMake script is:

```
# Path where CMake can find additional libraries
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH Libs)

# Boost
SET(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.47" "1.47.0")
SET(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS serialization)
```

I have a folder called "Libs" inside my project where third-party libraries such as DevIL and Boost are stored, so I set this first. It works fine for Devil and Boost header-only stuff, so I assume I should not need the BOOST_ROOT variable.
The Boost installation is the standard source distribution from boost.org which I compiled with [BJam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perforce_Jam#Boost.Jam). The libraries are stored in `boost_1_47_0\bin.v2\libs`, and I didn't change anything in the build process.

I think it is a bit odd, that the `boost_1_47_0\libs` folder doesn't contain any library files but BJam files and other stuff, but that shouldn't be a problem since this seems to be the normal way to build Boost on Windows from the source.

I looked at the Debug output from the `FindBoost.cmake` file (I'm using the default script from CMake 2.8) and it doesn't seem to look into `bin.v2`. Instead it searches `boost_ROOT/lib`, but when I copied the content from `bin.v2\libs` to lib it still didn't find anything.

So what is an elegant way to find Boost that will also work on other platforms with common Boost distributions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, I solved the problem, but I'm not fully satisfied with my solution.

In my opinion the problem was that BJam creates a too complex folder structure. Now I just copied the library files from "boost_1_47_0\bin.v2\libs\serialization\build\msvc-9.0\debug\link-static\threading-multi" to "boost_1_47_0\lib".

I have to do this by hand, but I'm not using that many Boost libraries, so this step is OK in my opinion. I will document my solution aside the CMake script, so other users should get along with that.

Comment: I read the manual (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) but used option 5.2. I found the stage directory with all the libraries in it and can now set this as my boost library dir, but next time I will try option 5.3.

Comment: You can also simply copy stage and boost (headers) directory around to make your own installation of Boost. e.g. boost/ -> C:\boost\include\boost and stage/* -> C:\boost\lib

Comment: I had the same problem and I think it shouldn't be the user's task to set the paths, but it was the only solution I found. Library's folder structure should be coherent with find_package. There's no point in complicating things. CMake is supossed to make the user things easy to install.

Answer (score 14):

I would try setting `BOOST_ROOT` inside your `CMakeLists.txt` file. I know that CMake 2.8.6 will find Boost 1.47.0 when you set the `Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS` variable since it works for me on Windows when I have `BOOST_ROOT` set.

Here is what I have in one project:

```
    set( BOOST_COMPONENTS_NEEDED serialization )

    # The following verifyies that BOOST_ROOT is set properly.
    if(NOT BOOST_ROOT AND NOT $ENV{BOOST_ROOT} STREQUAL "")
        FILE( TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{BOOST_ROOT} BOOST_ROOT )
        if( NOT EXISTS ${BOOST_ROOT} )
            MESSAGE( STATUS  ${BOOST_ROOT} " does not exist. Checking if BOOST_ROOT was a quoted string.." )
            STRING( REPLACE "\"" "" BOOST_ROOT ${BOOST_ROOT} )
            if( EXISTS ${BOOST_ROOT} )
                MESSAGE( STATUS "After removing the quotes " ${BOOST_ROOT} " was now found by CMake" )
            endif( EXISTS ${BOOST_ROOT})
        endif( NOT EXISTS ${BOOST_ROOT} )

    # Save the BOOST_ROOT in the cache
        if( NOT EXISTS ${BOOST_ROOT} )
            MESSAGE( WARNING ${BOOST_ROOT} " does not exist." )
        else(NOT EXISTS ${BOOST_ROOT})
            SET (BOOST_ROOT ${BOOST_ROOT} CACHE STRING "Set the value of BOOST_ROOT to point to the root folder of your boost install." FORCE)
            #SET (BOOST_INCLUDEDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/Include)
            #SET (BOOST_LIBRARYDIR ${BOOST_ROOT}/lib)
        endif( NOT EXISTS ${BOOST_ROOT} )

    endif(NOT BOOST_ROOT AND NOT $ENV{BOOST_ROOT} STREQUAL "")

    if( WIN32 AND NOT BOOST_ROOT )
        MESSAGE( WARNING "Please set the BOOST_ROOT environment variable." )
    endif( WIN32 AND NOT BOOST_ROOT )

    set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.47" "1.47.0")
    set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS       OFF)
    set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
    set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
    FIND_PACKAGE(Boost 1.47.0 COMPONENTS ${BOOST_COMPONENTS_NEEDED})
    if(Boost_FOUND)
        MESSAGE( STATUS "Setting up boost." )
        include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
        if(Boost_DEBUG)
            MESSAGE( STATUS "BOOST Libraries " ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
            FOREACH(BOOST_COMPONENT ${BOOST_COMPONENTS_NEEDED})
                STRING( TOUPPER ${BOOST_COMPONENT} BOOST_COMPONENT_UPCASE )
                MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost " ${BOOST_COMPONENT} ": " ${Boost_${BOOST_COMPONENT_UPCASE}_LIBRARY} )
                MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost " ${BOOST_COMPONENT} " Debug: " ${Boost_${BOOST_COMPONENT_UPCASE}_LIBRARY_DEBUG} )
                MESSAGE( STATUS "Boost " ${BOOST_COMPONENT} " Release: " ${Boost_${BOOST_COMPONENT_UPCASE}_LIBRARY_RELEASE} )
            ENDFOREACH(BOOST_COMPONENT)
        endif(Boost_DEBUG)
    endif(Boost_FOUND)
```

Comment: This help me a lot, thanks for this script. I'd to a a line just after the Boost_FOUND with this: LINK_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS}) otherwise it keeps saying the library was not found. Hope this help others having the same problem.

Comment: -- Could NOT find Boost
Boost version: 1.60.0
Boost include path: /usr/include
Detected version of Boost is too old. Requested version was 1.64 (or newer).
..... Even when adding what is mentioned in the comment above (Windows 10 / CLion)

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem with this before. For some reason b2 (aka BJam) created the Boost libraries with a leading "lib".

The CMake script will not look for a file named `libboost_thread.lib`. It will only find `boost_thread.lib`. Remove the leading `lib` and CMake should find them.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't help Now the name is something like boost_serialization-vc90-mt-1_47.lib instead of libboost_serialization-vc90-mt-1_47.lib - and if I want to use some more libraries I really don't want to rename them all so that cmake can find them. In my opinion, find_package should do all the work for me...

Comment: Do not rename the libs. The "lib" prefix is for static libs, without the prefix is for DLLs. You should build with runtime-link=shared instead.

Comment: @AndreasHaferburg In my case I was specifically trying to static link boost into my application.

Answer (score 0):

I came here with a similar issue and just wanted to say my fix was similar, but not exactly the same.

My install prefix was `C:\lib\boost\boost_1_57_0`. I set a `BOOST_ROOT` environment variable pointing to that directory, but CMake (3.1.0) still couldn't find the headers. I realized the headers defaulted to install to `C:\lib\boost\boost_1_57_0\include\boost-1_57\boost`. I'm not going to run multiple versions so I just moved the final Boost directory down one and removed the `boost-1_57` directory and ended up with headers here:

```
C:\lib\boost\boost_1_57_0\include\boost
```

And CMake found everything.

Comment: Isn't there a difference between ***environment*** variables and ***CMake*** variables?

Comment: Yes.  CMake's [FindBoost module](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindBoost.cmake) 
 uses the environment variable `BOOST_ROOT` in its attempts to locate Boost.  It looks like newer versions actually may also use the environment variable `BOOSTROOT`.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following option to the command line of CMake to tell CGAL to use the static Boost libraries:

```
-DCGAL_Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=true
```