# Can't find boost or python

Tags: python, c++, boost, cmake

I have tried most suggestions and am still failing somewhere. Can some one walk me through step by step? I'm using cmake 3.2.2 and vs2013.  I also have boost_1_57_0.

This is the error message camke keeps sending me

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1182 (message):
Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

Unable to find the Boost header files.  Please set BOOST_ROOT to the root
directory containing Boost or BOOST_INCLUDEDIR to the directory containing
Boost's headers.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/dlib-18.15/dlib/add_python_module:37 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)


CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:138 (message):
Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing: PYTHON_LIBRARIES PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS)
(Required is at least version "2.6")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:374 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.2/Modules/FindPythonLibs.cmake:205 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  C:/dlib-18.15/dlib/add_python_module:38 (FIND_PACKAGE)
  CMakeLists.txt:5 (include)
```

Is there something I can enter into the `CMakeLists.txt file`? If so can I have it in the exact way it should be entered?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at these posts and see if they help you. A lot of issues like this can be fixed by setting the paths in the top level CMakeLists.txt.

It should look something like this:

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:\boost")
```

Here are some other references to this same issue:

[cmake doesn't find boost libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077652/cmake-doesnt-find-boost-libraries)

[How can I get cmake to find my alternative boost installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016448/how-can-i-get-cmake-to-find-my-boost-installation)

Comment: BOOST_ROOT can also be set via the commandline (e.g. cmake -DBOOST_ROOT="C:\boost" <src directory>) or the CMake GUI.

Comment: thanks for the advice will post the results as soon as I get a successful run