# Boost 1.69 and CMake 3.13

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I have just updated my MSYS2 and received a new version of boost library 1.69.0. But after this update CMake 3.13.1 that must support this boost version says to me:

```
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2018.2.6/bin/cmake/win/share/cmake-3.13/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2100 (message):
  Unable to find the requested Boost libraries.

  Boost version: 1.69.0

  Boost include path: D:/msys64/mingw64/include

  Could not find the following Boost libraries:

      boost_chrono
      boost_filesystem
      boost_system

  No Boost libraries were found.  You may need to set BOOST_LIBRARYDIR to the
  directory containing Boost libraries or BOOST_ROOT to the location of
  Boost.
```

As i see CMake found boost 1.69.0 but not found Boost libraries. Why? With Boost 1.68.0 all works perfect.

**PROBLEM SOLVED:**

Today i cheked updates in MSYS and received an updated package
    mingw-w64-x86_64-boost-1.69.0-2

After that CMake found all Boost 1.69.0 libraries succesfuly

Comment: Oh I see boost-1.69.0 was released yesterday. I doubt `CMake` will find that being that CMake-3.13.1 was released last month. See my answer here for how to deal with newer boost versus cmake: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077652/cmake-doesnt-find-boost-libraries/8081804#8081804 the key is `set(Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS "1.69" "1.69.0")`

Comment: it didn't help me, nothing changed. Setting `BOOST_ROOT` is not an option because in MSYS2 using unix style directory tree and all libraries and includes placed in standart places.