# Building Azure-iot-Hub Python-SDk on Windows 10. How to set the path for BOOST and cmake

Tags: python-3.x, cmake, boost-python, azure-iot-hub, azure-sdk-python

I am trying to setup the Azure-IoT-Hub SDK for python. For C SDK it is compiling and building fine. But for python I am getting BOOST path error and Cmake error. I am trying to follow this link  https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/master/doc/python-devbox-setup.md#windows

I building the boost_1_66_0 using bootstrap.bat it generated b2.exe file and after running it I got binaries inside the C:\boost_1_66_0\stage\lib

I downloaded the cmake from https://cmake.org/download/ and past the C:\cmake-3.15.0-rc3-win64-x64\bin to Enviromental variable path.
But while running the cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" command in devloper command prompt for VS2017 it is showing errors..

```
C:\azure-iot-sdk-python\cmake>cmake .. -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27032.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.16.27032.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2017/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.16.27023/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:7 (set):
  implicitly converting 'build_python' to 'STRING' type.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- IoT Client SDK Version = 1.2.12
-- Looking for include file stdint.h
-- Looking for include file stdint.h - found
-- Looking for include file stdbool.h
-- Looking for include file stdbool.h - found
-- target architecture: x86
-- Performing Test CXX_FLAG_CXX11
-- Performing Test CXX_FLAG_CXX11 - Success
-- target architecture: x86
-- target architecture: x86
-- target architecture: x86
-- target architecture: x86
-- iothub architecture: x86
CMake Error at C:/cmake-3.15.0-rc3-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: python) (found version "1.67.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/cmake-3.15.0-rc3-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/cmake-3.15.0-rc3-win64-x64/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2142 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  device/iothub_client_python/CMakeLists.txt:28 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/azure-iot-sdk-python/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/azure-iot-sdk-python/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Is this a path problem? Please help in setting up the environment.
I am expecting .pyd file inside device/samples folder. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Issues like this can be fixed by setting the paths in the top level **`CMakeLists.txt.`**

```
set(BOOST_ROOT "C:\boost")
```

`**BOOST_ROOT**` can also be set via the commandline (e.g. `**cmake -DBOOST_ROOT="C:\boost" <src directory>**`) or the CMake GUI.

You can also refer below links for similar issues.

[CMake doesnt' find Boost Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8077652/cmake-doesnt-find-boost-libraries)

[CMake to find alternative Boost installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3016448/how-can-i-get-cmake-to-find-my-alternative-boost-installation)

Hope it helps.