# KDE "Activities Statistics Library" failed to build due to Boost_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND error

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qml

I'm trying to contribute to the KDE Project but the dependencies fails when it gets to KDE "Activities Statistics Library".
I followed all the rules:

https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Build_from_source/Install_the_dependencies

I used to kdesrc-build tool described in:

https://community.kde.org/Get_Involved/development

My question is has anyone on this site actually build KDE for source on Manjaro Linux?
This one program stops me dead when it comes to developing software for KDE. There's not much help with build issues yet.

Comment: Did you install boost? It seems to have not found the boost headers but at the same time it did not fail at the configure stage even though it did not have them

Comment: Boost is installed.  It's at version 1.72. I can't place where the build fails. Cmake just can't find boost for some reason.

Comment: Maybe your `CMake` version is too old and you need to set `Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS`  to allow the old CMake to recognize the new boost. I have an example in this 9+ year old answer: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081804/487892](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081804/487892)